# Is it possible to determine HOW a user authenticated by inspecting Kerberos packets?

Tags: authentication, kerberos, smartcard

Right now I'm seeing that password authentications are lacking a certificate in the  PADATA field and that smart cards have a certificate that can be decoded. However, is there a more detailed way to determine how a user authenticated? Biometric, password, smart card, etc.?

Charles.

Comment: I thought Kerberos used strong encryption, so what do you mean by _"inspecting Kerberos packets"_?